# How can I verify that I am using USB3 and not USB2 (Linux)?

Tags: linux, usb

I have a 4G LTE module (EM160R-GL) which has an M.2 connector, I have purchased 2 M.2 to PCIe adapters from 2 different manufacturers, let's call the first one `Josh` and the second one `Drake`.

When I connect the module via `Josh's` adapter, I run `lsusb -t`, and I can see the module connected in `USB3` mode.

When I connect the module via `Drake's` adapter, I run `lsusb -t`, and I can see it is connected in `USB2` mode. Drake's adapter is only rated to work in USB2 on the box.

When I contacted `Drake`, he said that I am right and that I am connecting in USB2 mode using his adapter, however according to the module spec sheet, he says:

> The EM160R module using PCI express and USB 2.0 connection. The USB
> connection will be all the time at speed 480.They mention USB3 in the
> way that USB 3.0 master can be connected to USB 2.0 interface. In this
> case the speed willbe still 480.

The product sped sheet: https://www.manualslib.com/manual/2033679/Quectel-Lte-A-Module-Series.html?page=38#manual

Can a device that is reporting a speed of 5000 (USB3) in `lsusb -t` really be using 480 (USB2) or is drake just wrong?

Comment: Can you post the actual `lsusb -tv` (and `lsusb.py -ci`) output? If it's a PCI device, it'll be bringing _its own_ USB host controller, not just attaching a device to the existing USB bus (which it has no acccess to), so there is a difference between the host controller reporting 5000M and the individual modem device reporting 5000M.

Comment: @user1686 I don't have access to it now, but I will post it later. You are right, it is a PCIe device that has its own controller. both the controller and modem are reporting 5000M, but I will post the full output later.